# Login and if / else statements in PHP/SQL?

Tags: php, sql, authentication

I have a login script. It checks against my database's user table to see if the values exist. I've added a 'close_account' column to the table to control if a user is allowed to log in. If 'close_account' = 1 they cant log in, if 'close_account' = 0 then they can log in.

I already have an if / else statement that shows if the login credentials used were invalid (i.e. that they don't exist in the database) so I need an extra check for the 'close_account' flag so that I can display a message to the user that tells them their account has been disabled.

Is this possible?

Here is my existing code:

```
// Check database to see if email and the hashed password exist there.
            $query = "SELECT id, email, close_account ";
            $query .= "FROM ptb_users ";
            $query .= "WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
            $query .= "AND password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
            $query .= "AND close_account = '0' ";
            $query .= "LIMIT 1";
            $result_set = mysql_query($query);
            confirm_query($result_set);

redirect_to("dashboard.php");
            } else {
                // email/password combo was not found in the database
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox\"><strong>Email/Password combination incorrect.</strong><br />
                    Please make sure your caps lock key is off and try again.</div>";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your logic in the below way.

```
 //confirm_query($result_set);
 if(mysql_num_rows($result_set) > 0) {
       redirect_to("dashboard.php");
  } else {
            // email/password combo was not found in the database
            $message = "<div class=\"infobox\"><strong>Email/Password combination incorrect.</strong><br />
                Please make sure your caps lock key is off and try again.</div>";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have close_account in the where clause of your query, then just test on that when you have verified that the details are correct.

```
$q = "SELECT id, email, close_account 
        FROM ptb_users 
       WHERE email = '$email'
         AND password = '$hashed_password'";

$results = mysql_query($q);
$user    = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);

if(!empty($user))
{
    if($user['close_account']) // If close_account is 1
    {
        // Display error, showing that account is closed.
    }
    else // If close_account is 0
    {
        redirect_to('dashboard.php');
    }
}
else 
{
    // Display error, showing that bad credentials were entered.
}
```

Comment: Why the concatenation abuse in $q? Just use a heredoc string as in http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: I've been working on a lot of legacy code that does it that way recently, kind of just got into the habit with single quote being faster than double quote moreso back in PHP < 4.3

Answer (score 0):

ok so heres my answer

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from ptb_users where WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."' and password = '".$_POST['password']."' ")
while($check_account = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $email_check = $check_account['email'];
  $pass_check = $check_account['password'];//whatever if this is hashed_password i dunno
  $blocked_acc = $check_account['close_account'];
}   
if($block_acc == 1) //or what ever your specs in the database are
{
 echo "Your Account has been blocked";
}
else if($email_check != $_POST['email'] && $pass_check != $_POST['password'])
{
 echo "Invalid E-mail or Password";
}
```

http://www.jaywebtechnologies.co.cc